# How to get button clicks in host fragment from dialog fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-alertdialog

I have a listFragment, where I want to display a DialogFragment (Yes/No) on listItemClick. I want to get back the user selection(Yes/No) in listFragment. I have read about the listener interface mechanism but that work with activity<->fragment. One way of doing this can be:

1. Define interface in dialog fragment containing yes/no button selection functions, and call these methods on alert dialog positive/negative button clicks.
2. Implement this interface in Main activity.
3. Initiate dialogFragment in listFragment onItem click.
4. Save user selection in activity.
5. get this choice in listFragment by another interface, implemented in Main activity.

But do we have any simple mechanism for this simple task? any example or code?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

There is another way how to get the result back from DialogFragment.

You can use [Fragment.setTargetFragment()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setTargetFragment%28android.app.Fragment,%20int%29). When creating an instance of your DialogFragment set target fragment to it. Then in DialogFragment you can get this fragment from [Fragment.getTargetFragment()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getTargetFragment%28%29).

For example, you can do it so:

```
public interface DialogClickListener {
    public void onYesClick();
    public void onNoClick();
}
```

```
public class MyListFragment extends ListFragment implements DialogClickListener {

    ...

    private void showDialog() {
        DialogFragment dialog = new MyDialogFragment();
        dialog.setTargetFragment(this, 0);
        dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "dialog");
    }

    @Override
    public void onYesClick() {
        // do something
    }

    @Override
    public void onNoClick() {
        // do something
    }
}
```

```
public class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    private DialogClickListener callback;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        try {
            callback = (DialogClickListener) getTargetFragment();
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException("Calling fragment must implement DialogClickListener interface");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setMessage("message")
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        callback.onYesClick();
                    }
                }).setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        callback.onNoClick();
                    }
                });

        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

Comment: Does not work with "import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;" and dialog.setTargetFragment(this, 0); My ListFragment gets me error: setTargetFragment
(android.app.Fragment,
int)
in Fragment cannot be applied
to
(com.xyz.xyz.CursorAdapterFragment,
int)

Comment: @powder366 got any solution for that??

Comment: Thanks J-rooft helped me a lot! everywhere I found activity to Dialog fragment communication! your answer helped me for making child fragment to Dialog fragment callbacks !

Comment: Wow, this should have been documented more clearly, I am always horribly passing callbacks around through activities.

Comment: This should how one Fragment communicate with other fragment.

Comment: I thought i need to pass data from fragment to fragment through activity. This is the best and simplest answer!!

Comment: Thank you Bro.. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can also use an event bus to facilitate the communication between components. Otto is a great library to use available here --> https://github.com/square/otto . It is made by the Square guys so you know its a quality open source project.

They have a sample in the repository that shows you how easy it is to use.

Comment: From the link: "This project is deprecated in favor of [RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava) and [RxAndroid ](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid) . These projects permit the same event-driven programming model as Otto, but they’re more capable and offer better control of threading." For those like me looking for this stuff. :)