# DialogFragment callback to Target Fragment using interface

Tags: android, android-fragments, interface, callback, android-dialogfragment

I am trying to send some data from a `dialogfragment` to the targeted `fragment` but its not working.

I have written the following code, but it through `exception`:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.x.x.FragmentAlertDialog$Communicator.setI(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

Code:

```
public class FragmentAlertDialog extends DialogFragment {

Communicator callback;

public interface Communicator {
    void setI(String name);
}

public static FragmentAlertDialog newInstance(String id, int title, int items) {
    FragmentAlertDialog frag = new FragmentAlertDialog();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("id", id);
    args.putInt("title", title);
    args.putInt("items", items);
    frag.setArguments(args);
    return frag;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    callback = (Communicator) getTargetFragment();
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    String id = getArguments().getString("id");
    int title = getArguments().getInt("title");
    String[] items = getResources().getStringArray(getArguments().getInt("items"));
    switch (id) {
        case MainActivity.DIALOG_1:
            return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                    .setTitle(title)
                    .setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            callback.setI("Important Data");
                        }
                    }).create();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Fragment Class

```
public class FragmentXYXY extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener, FragmentAlertDialog.Communicator {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.et_i:
            DialogFragment newFragment = FragmentAlertDialog.newInstance(MainActivity.DIALOG_I, R.string.i_select, R.array.i_array);
            newFragment.setTargetFragment(this, 0);
            newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "dialog");
    }
}

@Override
public void setI(String name) {
    textI.setText(name);
}
```

Can anybody please help.
Thank you

Code Modified- newFragment.setTargetFragment(this, 0);

Comment: what dose the getTargetFragment(); method do?

Comment: its a build in method, i am trying to get the fragment where the dialog is created

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you have to call [setTargetFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setTargetFragment(android.app.Fragment,%20int))

```
setTargetFragment(this, 0);
```

in order to get a reference `FragmentXYXY`, in your `DialogFragment`.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.et_i:
            DialogFragment newFragment = FragmentAlertDialog.newInstance(MainActivity.DIALOG_I, R.string.i_select, R.array.i_array);
            newFragment.setTargetFragment(this, 0);
            newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "dialog");
    }
}
```

Comment: error - android.support.v4.app.SuperNotCalledException: Fragment FragmentAlertDialog{20927aee #1 dialog} did not call through to super.onAttach()

Comment: *did not call through to super.onAttach()*

Comment: also tried this, not working------
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        callback = (Communicator) getTargetFragment();
    }

Comment: you did override onAttach on your DialogFragment and you didn't call the super

Comment: my bad did not notice that, after calling super---
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.x.x.FragmentAlertDialog$Communicator.setInstitute(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Comment: did you call `newFragment.setTargetFragment(this, 0);` ?

Comment: can you update the question, with the changes you made ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80979/discussion-between-thunderroid-and-blackbelt).

Comment: `setTargetFragment` is deprecated now

Answer (score 3):

For example, you can do it so:

```
public interface DialogClickListener {
    public void onYesClick();
    public void onNoClick();
}


public class MyListFragment extends ListFragment implements DialogClickListener {

    ...

    private void showDialog() {
        DialogFragment dialog = new MyDialogFragment();
        dialog.setTargetFragment(this, 0);
        dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "dialog");
    }

    @Override
    public void onYesClick() {
        // do something
    }

    @Override
    public void onNoClick() {
        // do something
    }
}


public class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    private DialogClickListener callback;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        try {
            callback = (DialogClickListener) getTargetFragment();
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException("Calling fragment must implement DialogClickListener interface");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setMessage("message")
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        callback.onYesClick();
                    }
                }).setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        callback.onNoClick();
                    }
                });

        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

for detail just refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13238959/how-to-get-button-clicks-in-host-fragment-from-dialog-fragment)

Comment: still same error

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.x.x.FragmentAlertDialog$Communicator.setI(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Comment: comment this line callback = (Communicator) getTargetFragment();

Comment: not working - java.lang.ClassCastException: com.x.x.MainActivity cannot be cast to com.x.x.FragmentAlertDialog$Communicator

Comment: this.callback=callback; not working -- (this) cannot be referanced from a non-static context

Comment: ohh right you are using static method. Then use setTarget and getTarget method. that is also good option.

Comment: can you please give me an example