# OnDismissListener in a DialogFragment

Tags: android, fragment, listener, dismiss

In my application I have a fragment which open a dialog fragment. In my dialog fragment I take in input from user some settings that in save in a static class, but I need a listener to inform my Fragment that the dialog was closed.

I use the code from the first answer of this link [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23786033/dialogfragment-and-ondismiss) but this part of code doesn't work because I have a fragment and not an activity. The onDismiss method is called in dialogfragment but the if statement fails and so doesn't call the fragment. I tried to replace that part with getFragmentManager and with getParentFragment and get/setTargetFragment but doesn't work.

Someone can help me please?

```
public void onDismiss(final DialogInterface dialog) {
    super.onDismiss(dialog);

    // code I've tried
    final FragmentManager fragment = getFragmentManager();
    if (fragment instanceof DialogInterface.OnDismissListener) {
        ((DialogInterface.OnDismissListener) fragment).onDismiss(dialog);
    }

    // original answer code  
    /*final Activity activity = getActivity();
    if (activity instanceof DialogInterface.OnDismissListener) {
        ((DialogInterface.OnDismissListener) activity).onDismiss(dialog);
    }*/

}
```

Comment: did you tried interface callback ?

Comment: I'm pretty new of Android, can you explain me more please?

Comment: use `final Fragment fragment = getParentFragment()`. and check whether the parent fragment is the Fragment what is implement onDismissListener or not. If not, check your fragment tree.

Answer (score 3):

This is an old issue but I found no solution I am happy with. I don't like passing any Listeners to my DialogFragment or set a TargetFragment, because that may break on orientation change. What do you think about this?

```
    MyDialog d = new MyDialog();
        d.show(fragmentManager, "tag");
        fragmentManager.registerFragmentLifecycleCallbacks(new FragmentManager.FragmentLifecycleCallbacks() {
                @Override
            public void onFragmentViewDestroyed(FragmentManager fm, Fragment f) {
                super.onFragmentViewDestroyed(fm, f);
                //do sth      
        fragmentManager.unregisterFragmentLifecycleCallbacks(this);
                }
            }, false);
```

Comment: I completely change my code to find a solution, it was an old project that is finished 1 year ago so I can't try this new code to solve my old problem. Btw the code you posted should work and I also like the approce also you answerd to an old question.

Comment: To be honest, I even found a better solution. The reason you cannot use getDialog on the DialogFragment and then set a dismiss listener is that the FragmentTransaction has not been executed. So when you executePendingTransactions on the FragmentManager getDialog will not  return null.

Comment: Without appcompat registerFragmentLifecycleCallbacks `Call requires API level 26`

Answer (score 1):

You can try interface call back,

create an interface in your dialog fragment

```
    public interface Listener{
     void onDismiss();
    }
```

implement this in your fragment,

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements MyDialogFragment.Listener{

  @Override
public void onDismiss(){
  //write the operations here   
 }
}
```

now in your dialog fragment recieve the object of your parent fragment, 
ex:

```
public void setListener(Listener listener){
 this.mListener = listener;
}
```

you have to call this method from your fragment, to set the listener.

now in your onDismiss() method of your dialog fragment call onDismiss using this reference

ex

```
@Override
public void onDismiss(){
  mListener.onDismiss();
}
```

do the necessory null checks

check this below link too

[How to get button clicks in host fragment from dialog fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13238959/how-to-get-button-clicks-in-host-fragment-from-dialog-fragment)

Comment: when I use setListener(this) doesn't work because I'm in a View.OnClickListener so doesn't accept "this". Any advice?

Comment: I solved it, I use totally different approch. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can another way to achieve it:

```
// create a function in YourFragment
public void myDissmiss();
// change your newInstance(bitmap) of your dialog fragment
public static DialogFragmentImage newInstance(Bitmap b,YourFragment f);
```

then you can call `yourfragment.myDissmiss()` in your `public void onDismiss(final DialogInterface dialog)` of `DialogFragmentImage`.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand your answer.